# I'm getting unrealistically low gas fee's when deploying an ERC-721 contract on testnet

Tags: ethereum, ethernet, smartcontracts, truffle, remix

I deployed my smart contract(ERC-721) on truffle (Rinkeby | Ropsten | local node) and again on Remix and I keep getting an average cost of 0.0165 ether. This gas fee seems unrealistic to me, even though my contract is pretty simple.

I finally tried deploying to MAINNET using Truffle and the transactions stopped due to a low gas value. I switched over to REMIX and the new total gas fee is 0.65 ($2500) ether.

Is this a realistic amount to deploy a smart contract? or do I need to change some setting on remix?

Do the testnet's give a good representation of what gas fee will cost on mainnet ?

Comment: Note that gas fees are not static. They change depending on demand. The old "normal" gas fees (eg. around 2019 and 2020) was not as high as it is today. The reason the current gas fee is so high is due to popularity of NFT. We saw this happen with the original NFT cryptokitties.co. I was working on a few projects (mostly ICO) that was basically screwed when cryptokitties came out in 2017. Testnets do not even attempt to monitor mainnet gas fees. So what you are seeing was the normal gas around 2016

Comment: I was worries that would be the case, so an average price of 0.55 ether for a simple smart contract is a realistic cost in 2021?

Answer (score 2):

The amount of gas used from gas limit, not the gas price is going to be consistent between mainnet and testnets as the gas used from gas limit represents the amount of work that needs to be done to process the transaction logic in the EVM. Gas price (how much you pay for a unit of gas used) fluctuates as it is dependent on market economics/game theory, which is going to be very different on a test network vs live network.

References

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/